# Tabs with multiple tags automatically become modified

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

This has started to happen on **Edge** (the same also on **IE11**) today.

I have made a Tab with 4 Tags joining them using the **ANY** option. When I click the tab, the `star (*)` symbol automatically appears on the left of the Tab caption and the button **SAVE** becomes enabled.
Saving the Tab seems to fix the modified flag but just switching to another Tab and returning on the previous multiple-tag Tab restart the odd behavior.

This doesn't happen in a Tab where there is a single Tag added to the filter criteria.

Don't known if it is related, but, at the same time, [notifications started to work erratically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311238/notification-on-custom-tabs-works-erratically).

Comment: +1. Exactly the same problem here. I tried even clearing cookies.

Comment: Same problem on Chrome.

Comment: I can repro in any browser I try. It's improved from yesterday when creating a tab with multiple tags was causing a new "phantom" tab to appear.

Comment: Today I noticed the same problem on Safari 9 too.

Comment: Firefox 42.0, same issue.

Comment: It also happens to me - mine is "java and not android" + filter.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in the latest upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in build `2015.12.16.3985` (meta) and  `2015.12.16.3090` (main).

Comment: Confirmed on Edge and Firefox...