# Notification on custom tabs works erratically

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

As explained in the [new navigation manifesto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) I am well aware that notifications are not ready for prime-time, but, till yesterday they worked in a on-off way that was unnerving but with the off-time somewhat acceptable.

Now there is a different problem. The notifications appear in the caption of the custom tabs as a number enclosed in parenthesys but the updated bar used to refresh the page is missing as you can see here (This has been observed on Edge and IE11)

[image]

After some test I can reproduce the problem (and be able to restore the expected functionality) in this way.

- Select a custom tab (with an high frequency of notifications)
- Wait for a new notification and check if the update bar appears
- Switch to another custom tab and wait some time (a couple of minutes is enough)
- Switch back on the first tab and wait for new notifications

At this point, when new notifications arrive, the circled number appears but the update bar is missing.

Now if you want to see the new questions you have to click again on another tab and return back on the interested one. But the loop repeats and the update bar will stay hidden somewhere.

Pressing F5 (refresh the page) seems to restore the expected behavior of the notification bar until you click again on another tab.

Comment: Just ran into this one. Very annoying that I have to switch tabs which involves two clicks rather than one click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have been fixed a couple of weeks back. Can you repro?

Comment: Yes, now it works without the need of a refresh (albeit I have signaled another problem with multiple-tags tabs when you hit the refresh button/key on that tab)